# Ignoring (skipping) an NUnit test case without throwing an exception

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have a requirement to **not** run a test case during certain times in the month and I would like to ignore or skip the relevant test(s) when applicable. So far the only attribute I have found that makes sense is `Assert.Ignore();`. Unfortunately triggering this method throws an `IgnoreException` <s>and as a consequence the NUnit `TearDown` will not be triggered. This is not ideal as I have code that I would like to execute after each test case ***irrespective*** of the test outcome.</s> *I was incorrect in my assumption please find comments below...*

In an ideal world I wish I could just set the test outcome in my ignore / skipped part of the code, example:

```
else
{
    //it's after the 25th of the month let's skip this test case
    TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome == ResultState.Ignored;
}
```

But I understand that `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome` is only a `Get` for good reason and it would most likely just open a can of worms with people just setting their tests as passed when they should not etc..

```
[Test]
[TestCase(TestName = "Test A")]
[Description("Test A will be testing something.")]
[Category("Regression Test Pack")]
public void Test_Case_1()
{
    sessionVariables = new Session().SetupSession(uiTestCase: true);

    if (DateTime.Now.Day <= 25)
    {
        //let's test something!
    }
    else
    {
        //it's after the 25th of the month let's skip this test case
        Assert.Ignore();
    }
}

[TearDown]
public void Cleanup()
{
    sessionVariables.TeardownLogic(sessionVariables);
}
```

Comment: Does using `Assert.Inconclusive` (or `Assert.Pass`) solve the problem? In your case `Assert.Inconclusive` makes more sense semantically imho because the test actually wasn't skipped but you realized that you cannot come out with a reasonable result.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg unfortunately all of those simply skip the `[TearDown]` method invocation.

Comment: Which version of NUnit are you using? Are you sure the `[TearDown]` is not getting invoked? I tested on NUnit 3.12.0 using both `Assert.Ignore` and `Assert.Inconclusive`. In both cases, the `[TearDown]` was invoked.

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell I went and did a retest and it seems that I made an incorrect assumption regarding the teardown not being called, it does seem to be. I will remove this post as even though the exception is thrown the correct teardown logic may be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you discovered, use of `Assert.Ignore` does not cause the teardown to be skipped. (If it did, that would be an NUnit bug, because teardown must always be run if setup has been run)

So, your choice of how to end the test depends on how you want the result to be shown...

- Simply returning causes the test to pass, without any special message.
- `Assert.Pass` does the same thing but allows you to include a message.
- `Assert.Ignore` issues an "ignored" warning and allows you to specify a reason. The warning is propagated so that the result of the run as a whole is also "Warning".
- `Assert.Inconclusive` gives an "inconclusive" result, which is intended to mean that the test could not be run due to some external factor. You may also specify the specific reason and the overall run result is not affected.
- As an alternative to `Assert.Inconclusive`, you could use `Assume.That` with an appropriate test. For example, the following code would trigger the "inconclusive" result after the 25th of the month:

```cs
    Assume.That(DateTime.Now.Day <= 25);
```

For what it's worth, the "Inconclusive" result is intended for exactly this kind of situation. It means that the test could not be run for reasons beyond it's control. "Ignored" results are intended to be treated as a problem to eventually be solved by the team, although many folks use it differently.

From the point of view of NUnit's design, `Assume.That` is the most natural way to produce the result. You would normally place it at the beginning of the test or the `SetUp` method, before any other code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response @Charlie, I will definitely experiment with the  `Assume.That` logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can just `return` instead of doing an assert.

```
public void Test_Case_1()
{
    sessionVariables = new Session().SetupSession(uiTestCase: true);

    if (DateTime.Now.Day <= 25)
    {
        //let's test something!
    }
    else
    {
        //it's after the 25th of the month let's skip this test case
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't mark the test as "skipped" in test reports: it will be marked as "pass" instead, which might not be what the OP wants

Comment: Thanks @Connell.O'Donnell your solution seems to be the closest as it will allow my `[TearDown]` procedure to execute. The fact that it marks the test as passed is not ideal to a casual observer but I think I will have to work around that. (If I do not receive a better solution, I will mark yours as the best solution.